# Redirecting “/” to “/sub-directory” When Running Rails App as a Sub-Directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, routes

I am running my rails app as sub-directory (for apache mapping reasons):

config.ru:

```
map '/sub-directory' do
    run Rails.application
end
```

application.rb:

```
config.root_directory = "/sub-directory/"
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/sub-directory'
```

so now my app (it's root) is ran from the route http://localhost:3000/sub-directory. The problem is when I go to http://localhost:3000/ I get the page:

```
Not Found: /
```

I understand I am getting that because my app isn't running in there anymore but I would like that route to redirect to http://localhost:3000/sub-directory. Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

if this helps, routes.rb:

```
require 'resque/server'
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get "handle/:handle" => "handles#index"
  get "/tag/:hashtag" => "tags#index"

  get "handles/:handle" => "handles#index"
  get "/tags/:hashtag" => "tags#index"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    :registrations => "registrations",
    :passwords => "passwords"
  }

  devise_scope :user do 
    get "/email" => "registrations#email"
    post "/registrations/check_email" => "registrations#check_email"
    get "/users/sign_in" => "registrations#signup"
  end



  authenticated :user do
    devise_scope :user do
      root :to => redirect("app"), as: :authenticated_root
      get "/app", :to => 'reports#index'
    end
  end

  unauthenticated do
    devise_scope :user do
      root to: 'registrations#new'
    end
  end

  get '/oauth' => 'social_platforms#new'

  get "/auth/:provider/callback" => "social_platforms#create"

  get   '/login', :to => 'sessions#new', :as => :login

  # match '/auth/failure' => 'sessions#failure', :via => [:get]

  # get '/reports', to: 'pages#reports', as: :reports
  resources :reports, only: [:show, :index]
  get '/get_report', to: 'reports#get_report'
  get '/check_token', to: 'reports#check_token'

  mount Resque::Server.new, at: "/resque"

  get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

Comment: What's your routes.rb?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon edited and included it in the OP

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but issue here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21193 says adding `root to: redirect('sub-directory')` solves the issue.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work, the problem is when I go to 'localhost:3000/' my rails app doesn't even seem to get hit because it's running at a level higher then that at 'localhost:3000/sub-directory'